# See how the color is being changed with input type=color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to see the color being changed whilst I am changing it, not after I click somewhere else so I see the results. Like in inspect element, we are changing color and watching live - how is it being changed and how to do the same with js dom? I tried addEventListener("mousemove"), addEventListener("mousedown") and addEventListener("change")

[image]

```js
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("change",function(e){
  document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundColor = e.target.value;
})
```

```css
#a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<input type="color" id="b">
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTTxJ.gif)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTTxJ.gif)

As you can see on the code, it is not changing in live mode, I am changing and after changing I am clicking anywhere else and the the color is being changed, I want it like in the gif above, change and see the changes at the same time

Comment: AFAIK this doesn't work with the built-in color input. You have to make your own!

Comment: If you are interested, I can suggest how it works in Vue3

Comment: @Dom It does. You just have to use a different event.

Comment: I tried it out with the "input" event type and it didn't work. But now I know better! thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`change` is only triggered when the dialogue is closed.
You want `input` instead:

> Tracking color changes
>
> As is the case with other `<input>` types, there are two events that can
> be used to detect changes to the color value: `input` and `change`. `input`
> is fired on the `<input>` element every time the color changes. The
> `change` event is fired when the user dismisses the color picker. In
> both cases, you can determine the new value of the element by looking
> at its `value`.

(Source: [MDN | `<input type="color">` -> Tracking color changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color#tracking_color_changes))

```js
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("input", function() {
  console.log(this.value);
  document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundColor = this.value;
})
```

```css
#a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<input type="color" id="b">
```